# I am very confused with the concept of using pointers in c

Tags: c, pointers, types

I think I have misconceptions in my understanding on pointers?

Based on my understanding , `int * twenties` means that twenties is a pointer to an `int` .

So for `*twenties = dollars/20;` , the `*twenties` here refers to the value of the pointer?

In `pay_amount(money, &twenties, &tens, &fives, &ones);`, the pointer `twenties` is storing the address of `&twenties` in the function of `pay_amount`? Wouldn't the twenties in `printf("$20 bills: %d\n", twenties);` print out the address instead of the value ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void pay_amount(int dollars, int *twenties, int *tens, int *fives, int *ones);

int main(void) {

    int money = 0, twenties, tens, fives, ones;

    printf("Enter a dollar amount: ");
    scanf("%d", &money);
    pay_amount(money, &twenties, &tens, &fives, &ones);

    printf("$20 bills: %d\n", twenties); // why isnt not *twenties??? I got an error if I put *twenties
    printf("$10 bills: %d\n", tens);
    printf(" $5 bills: %d\n", fives);
    printf(" $1 bills: %d\n", ones);

    return 0;
}

void pay_amount(int dollars, int *twenties, int *tens, int *fives, int *ones) {

    *twenties = dollars / 20;
    dollars -= *twenties * 20;
    *tens = dollars / 10;
    dollars -= *tens * 10;
    *fives = dollars / 5;
    dollars -= *fives * 5;
    *ones = dollars;
}
```

Comment: In your main, you declared twenties as an int. Why do you want it to be an int* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `twenties` in the `main()` and the `twenties` in the `pay_amount` function are different types.

While calling the `pay_amount()` from `main()`, you're passing the address of `twenties` of `main()`, and storing that in `twenties`  (which is local to the block scope of the function) of `pay_amount`.

The type of `twenties` in `main()` is `int`, the type of `twenties` in `pay_amount` is `int *`.

If you wish, you can use two different variable names altogether.

So, in `main()`, `twenties` is an `int`, and a print statement like

```
 printf("$20 bills: %d\n", twenties);
```

is correct. Point to note, if you want to print the `twenties` inside the `pay_amount()` function call, you have to use `*twenties`, as you'd have expected, as that one is of type `int *`.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you declare two variables as:

```
int data_holder;
int* pointer;
```

And assign values to them as:

```
data_holder = 10;
pointer = &data_holder;
```

What happens is this - compiler allocates memory for `data_holder` as well as `pointer`. Now, when you store 10 in `data_holder` and use `&` to get its address and store it in `pointer`, a link is created. To access the value 10 - you may either use `data_holder` or **de-reference** `pointer`.

*EDIT*:
When we use `*` during declaration of a pointer variable, it tells the compiler to treat the variable differently. When we use `*` again for that declared pointer, we are essentially **de-referencing** the pointer - accessing the value stored at the memory location it is pointing to.

More concretely;

```
printf("The value of data_holder is %d", data_holder);
printf("The value of data_holder is %d", *pointer);
```

Similarly, the value 10 can be modified in two ways;

```
data_holder = 200;       //The value is changed from 10 to 200
*pointer = 300;          //The value is changed from 200 to 300
```

Inside your function, `twenties` etc. are pointers, whereas in `main()` the `twenties` etc. are integers.

Comment: You should explain that when you prefix a pointer with * you are referring to the contents or value of the variable pointed to.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I have mentioned de-referencing !

Comment: But if this guy doesn’t understand the terminology then more generic explanations might be useful. I know what you mean but he might not. Or turn the word into a link to a description of the term in the standards.